# + and - control options in react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-leaflet

Is there a way in which I can remove the "+" and "-" symbols
from my react-leaftlet map container?

[image: + and - symbols]

This is my mapContainer element:

```
<MapContainer
    center={[0.0, 0.0]}
    zoom={2}
    attributionControl={false}
    doubleClickZoom={false}
    boxZoom={false}
    zoomSnap={0.2}>
    <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
</MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`zoomControl`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomcontrol) map creation option, which is ported as a prop in React Leaflet:

```
<MapContainer
    zoomControl={false}
</MapContainer>
```

> When creating a `MapContainer` element, its props are used as options to create the Map instance.